# How to suppress "Number of stages in the query (nnn) exceeds the soft limit" warning in Presto DB

Tags: presto

I've tried:

- passing `--session query_max_stage_count=150` to presto CLI client.
- setting `set session query_max_stage_count = 150` inside a REPL session.
- setting `set session query_max_stage_count = 150` as the first command of a script passed using `-f`.

All to no avail. The `query_max_stage_count` seems to be somewhat recognized since passing it an invalid (say, non numeric) value triggers an error.

Answer (score 3):

The `query_max_stage_count` governs only the hard stages count limit.

You can observe this by setting this to a low value:

```
presto> SET SESSION query_max_stage_count = 2;
SET SESSION

presto> SELECT DISTINCT name FROM (SELECT name FROM tpch.tiny.nation UNION ALL SELECT name FROM tpch.tiny.nation);
Query 20200621_080512_00011_gd9gz failed: Number of stages in the query (4) exceeds the allowed maximum (2). [...]
```

Currently, the "soft stages limit" (the threshold above which a warning is issued) is configurable only in the `config.properties` with `query.stage-count-warning-threshold` property and there is no session property to override this setting.

If you feel the warning should also be controlled by a session property, please file a new issue at https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/new.